# Problem with updating only some fields of entities in Google Cloud Datastore

Tags: google-cloud-platform, nosql, google-cloud-datastore, sql-update

I created an entity in Google Cloud Datastore using Python this way:

```
client = datastore.Client()

key = client.key('EntityType', id)
entity = datastore.Entity(key=key)
entity.update({'id': id, 'property_0': value_0, 'property_1': value_1,})
```

After this, when I check my entities list, I have a new entity with the 3 properties `id`, `property_0` and `property_1`

In another function, I only updated `property_2` which I do so this way

```
key = client.key('EntityType', id)
entity = datastore.Entity(key=key)
entity.update({'property_1': new_value_1,})
```

When I check the entities list after this, I only see `property_2` of my entity with the new value.

How can I update only `property_1` of the entity while still keeping the other ones?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to fetch it first

```
key = client.key('EntityType', id)
entity = client.get(key)
entity.update({'property_2': new_value_2,})
```

Answer (score 2):

If you just want to update some properties of your entity, you should not use the `.update()` method, this method removes properties that you do not assign any value. Instead you could manually set the value for the property you want to change, like in the example below:

```
# We first create the entity with the properties we want by using the update method.
client = datastore.Client()
key = client.key('EntityType', id)
entity = datastore.Entity(key=key)
entity.update({'property_0': 'a_string_value', 'property_1': 123})
client.put(entity)

# Then later we just fetch that entity and change the property we want.
client = datastore.Client()
key = client.key('EntityType', id)
entity = datastore.Entity(key=key)
entity['property_0'] = 'a_different_string_value'
client.put(entity)
```